# onActivityResult() only triggers when Camera is cancelled

Tags: android, camera

I'm having some trouble using the Camera intent in Android. I want to be able to take
a picture and to use the picture later (retreiving the URI). Here's the code:

```
newPicBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            PhotoChoiceActivity.this.launchCameraIntent();
        }

    });

public void launchCameraIntent()
{
    //create camera intent              
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    //set fileUri
    MediaManager manager = new MediaManager();
    manager.setPictureName(currentItemToAdd.toString());
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, manager.getOutputMediaFileUri());      
    startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == 100){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved to: " + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

So basically the button calls the launchCameraIntent() method. The MediaManager creates a file, and I use the file URI in the intent.putExtra to indicate where the file should be saved. The Camera intent is called, but here is the problem: the onActivityResult() only gets triggered when I cancel my camera intent. So it doesn't get triggered at all when I accept the picture that I've taken.

Hope you can help!

Comment: Where is the MediaManager class?  Do you have the proper file permissions for where you are creating the URI?

Comment: You should ahve a second method in the second activity, for the callback - `Intent return = new Intent();
 return.putExtra("result",result);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
 finish();` in order to notify the for the taken picture.

Comment: I'm using the right file permissions (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), @g00dy could you please elaborate? What second Activity? The Camera intent that I'm launching is a default Android activity.

Comment: One more thing - are you sure that the path you give for the saved image is EXISTING and that the folder you're saving this IS EXISTING. This is pretty important, because the camera will not stop if this is not put in place.

Comment: Yes, both the folder and file are existing, if they are not existing they are created.

Comment: It is most likely a problem with file path. Make sure it is something like this: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "somename"`. Notice the `File.separator`, because `getPath()` doesn't provide `/` at the end.